# ASP.Net can connect to MySQL server, but i cant pull back data?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, networking, phpmyadmin

I am using ASP.NET C# to try and connect to a MySQL server to pull back data into a Gridview. I can connect, but I can't pull back any data. It simply isn't there. There is data on the SQL server of course, but I just can't seem to get in back into my site. Any ideas?

Code for ref:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){   

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlDataAdapter adpater = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    string query;
    string connString = "Server=Server address; Database=sql8118918; Uid=my username; Pwd=my password; ";

    conn = new MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connString;       
        try
        {
           conn.Open();
           adpater = new MySqlDataAdapter();
           comm = new MySqlCommand();
           data = new DataTable();
           query = "SELECT * FROM products";

           comm.Connection = conn;
           comm.CommandText = query;

           adpater.SelectCommand = comm;
           adpater.Fill(data);
           GridView1.DataSource = data;
           logLabel.Text = ("Connection Successful !");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Like I said I can connect but no data is pulled back.
I have also tried to put the data into a string, and then display that string on the front end but all I get is this in the string ?

```
System.Data.DataRowCollection
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call DataBind() method after set the DataSource property. Take a look [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You are so welcome, I know you would do the same for me ;-)